# Beginner - add multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to find the sum of all positive multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000. After adding the portion that's supposed to remove the multiples of 3 from the sum of the multiples of 5, gprolog will keep spitting out "No" for the query `?- sigma(1000,N).`

The problem apparently lies in sigma5, but I can't quite spot it:

```
sigma(Num, Result) :- sigma3(Num, 3, Result3),
                      sigma5(Num, 5, Result5),
                      Result is Result3 + Result5.

sigma3(Num, A, Result) :- A < Num,
                          Ax is A+3,
                          sigma3(Num, Ax, ResultX),
                          Result is ResultX + A.
sigma3(Num, A, Result) :- A >= Num,
                          Result is 0.

sigma5(Num, A, Result) :- A < Num,
                          mod3 is A mod 3,
                          0 \= mod3,
                          Ax is A+5,
                          sigma5(Num, Ax, ResultX),
                          Result is ResultX + A.
sigma5(Num, A, Result) :- A < Num,
                          mod3 is A mod 3,
                          0 == mod3,
                          Ax is A+5,
                          sigma5(Num, Ax, ResultX),
                          Result is ResultX.
sigma5(Num, A, Result) :- A >= Num,
                          Result is 0.
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog has never been popular for it's arithmetic capabilities.

This is due to the need to represent 'term constructors' for symbolic processing, without undue evaluation, so when actual arithmetic is required we must explicitly allocate the 'space' (a variable) for the result, instead that 'passing down' an expression. This lead to rather verbose and unpleasant code.

But using some popular extension, like CLP(FD), available in GProlog as well as SWI-Prolog, we get much better results, not readily available in other languages: namely, a closure of the integer domain over the usual arithmetic operations. For instance, from the SWI-Prolog CLP(FD) library, a 'bidirectional' factorial

```
n_factorial(0, 1).
n_factorial(N, F) :- N #> 0, N1 #= N - 1, F #= N * F1, n_factorial(N1, F1).

?- n_factorial(X, 3628800).
X = 10 .
```

Anyway, here is a simple minded solution to the original problem, similar to what you attempted, but using an *accumulator* to compute result. This simple trick allows writing a *tail recursive* procedure, that turns out in better efficiency.

```
sigma(Num, Result) :-
    sigma(1, Num, 0, Result).

sigma(N, M, Acc, Tot) :-
    (   N < M, !,
        (   (0 is N mod 3 ; 0 is N mod 5)
        ->  Sum is Acc + N
        ;   Sum is Acc
        ),
        N1 is N + 1,
        sigma(N1, M, Sum, Tot)
    ;   Tot is Acc
    ).
```

Test:

```
?- sigma(1000, X).
X = 233168 .
```

Comment: +1: Maybe one additional remark: `library(clpfd)` in SWI and YAP compiles above program such that the traditional (is)/2-modes are of comparable efficiency to naïve (is)/2!

Answer (score 4):

As integers are involved, consider using [finite domain constraints](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html). For example, with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- findall(N, (N mod 3 #= 0 #\/ N mod 5 #= 0, N in 0..999, indomain(N)), Ns),
   sum(Ns, #=, Sum).
Ns = [0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18|...],
Sum = 233168.
```

Comment: Your loss ;-). But in all seriousness: All serious Prolog systems provide CLP(FD), I was only using SWI as one specific example.

Comment: @Cubic: Without constraints, one would replace `N in 0..999, indomain(N)` by `between(0,999,N)` at the beginning: `findall(N, (between(0,999,N),\+ \+ (N mod 3=:=0;N mod 5=:= 0)), Ns).`

Answer (score 1):

```
mod3 is A mod 3,
```

(as well all the other occurrences of mod3) should be Mod3 since it is a variable.
with that fix, the program runs correctly (at least for N=1000)

btw here is my solution (using higher-order predicates):

```
sum(S):-
    findall(X,between(1,999,X),L),       % create a list with all numbers between 1 and 999
    include(div(3),L,L3),                % get the numbers of list L which are divisible by 3
    include(div(5),L,L5),                % get the numbers of list L which are divisible by 5
    append(L3,L5,LF),                    % merge the two lists
    list_to_set(LF,SF),                  % eliminate double elements
    sumlist(SF,S).                       % find the sum of the members of the list

div(N,M):-
    0 is M mod N.
```

it's less efficient of course but the input is too small to make a noticeable difference

Comment: Ouch, this must be the 10th time today I got problems because I wrote variable names in lower case (I'm just so damn used to it...). Thanks.  Does gprolog know findall though?

Comment: `findall/3` is defined by the standard. You should still try using SWI-Prolog instead if you can, though, it is much more complete.

Comment: @Cubic it's normal I think xd I havent tried findall/3 in gprolog but it's pretty basic as Daniel Lyons said. anyway, it is not really essential in this case; just used to avoid writing [1,2,3,...999] (which can also be done by a simple recursion anyway). nonetheless, I suggest learning how findall/3 works.

Answer (score 0):

This all seems very complicated to me.

```
sum_of( L , S ) :-
  L > 0 ,
  sum_of( 0 , L , 0 , S )
  .

sum_of( X , X , S , S ) .    % if we hit the upper bound, we're done.
sum_of( X , L , T , S ) :-   % if not, look at it.
  X < L ,                    % - backtracking once we succeeded.
  add_mult35( X , T , T1 ) , % - add any multiple of 3 or 5 to the accumulator
  X1 is X + 1 ,              % - next X
  sum_of( X1 , L , T1 , S )  % - recurse
  . 

add_mult35( X , T , T ) :-  % no-op if X is
  X mod 3 =\= 0 ,           % - not a multiple of 3, and
  X mod 5 =\= 0 ,           % - not a multiple of 5
  !.                        %
add_mult35( X , T , T1 ) :- % otherwise,
  T1 is T + X               % increment the accumulator by X
  .
```

This could be even more concise than it is.

> Aside from my code probably being extraordinarily horrible (it's actually longer than my C solution, which is quite a feat on it's own),

ANSI C:

```
int sum_multiples_of_three_and_five( int lower_bound , int upper_bound )
{
  int sum = 0 ;

  for ( int i = lower_bound ; i <= upper_bound ; ++i )
  {
    if ( 0 == i % 3 || 0 == i % 5 )
    {
      sum += i ;
    }
  }

  return sum ;
}
```